# How to convert pandas single column data frame to series or numpy vector

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data frame just single column.

```
import pandas as pd
tdf =  pd.DataFrame({'s1' : [0,1,23.4,10,23]})
```

Currently it has the following shape.

```
In [54]: tdf.shape
Out[54]: (5, 1)
```

How can I convert it to a Series or a numpy vector so that the shape is simply `(5,)`

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can simply index the series you want. Example -

```
tdf['s1']
```

Demo -

```
In [24]: tdf =  pd.DataFrame({'s1' : [0,1,23.4,10,23]})

In [25]: tdf['s1']
Out[25]:
0     0.0
1     1.0
2    23.4
3    10.0
4    23.0
Name: s1, dtype: float64

In [26]: tdf['s1'].shape
Out[26]: (5,)
```

If you want the values in the series as numpy array, you can use `.values` accessor , Example -

```
In [27]: tdf['s1'].values
Out[27]: array([  0. ,   1. ,  23.4,  10. ,  23. ])
```

Comment: or perhaps assign the series to a numpy array for further manipulation, ie. np.asarray(tdf['s1'])

Comment: Yea, but I think `tdf['s1'].values` would be cleaner.

Comment: This can have the following error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39474056/valueerror-object-too-deep-for-desired-array

Comment: If you wish to avoid reference to the column name, you can alternatively do `tdf.iloc[:,0]` to get the leftmost column, `tdf.iloc[:,1]` for the next one...